# Octave error when trying to plot function N*log2(N)

Tags: octave

Im trying to plot this function in Octave and I'm getting an error I dont understand.  I've successfully plotted other functions, but for some reason this one isnt working.

```
N=[1:1:50];

y1Values = N*log2(N);

%plot (n, y1Values, 'LineWidth',2, n,y2Values, 'LineWidth',3);

plot (N, [ y1Values' ], 'LineWidth',3);

legend("e^N");
```

This produces this error

```
error: asstemp: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x50, op2 is 1x50)
```

error: called from
    asstemp at line 2 column 10

I dont know why the * would be a problem.  It hasnt with any of the other expressions.  Do I need to write the expression a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `N` is a vector `log2(N)` also returns a vector so you are trying to multiply two vectors. But `*` is a matrix multiplication. What you want is elemenwise multiplication (`.*`): `y1Values = N.*log2(N);`